# COUNTIF Statements: Range Across All Sheets + Cell Reference as Criterion

Tags: google-sheets

**1) Range Across All Sheets:**

I've googled everything but nothing. Basically, I need a formula that looks for the same range across all sheets.

My current formula looks like this:

```
=COUNTIF(Aug_15!$G:$G, "Shaun")+countif(July_15!$G:$G, "Shaun)+countif(June_15!$G:$G, "Shaun")+countif(May_15!$G:$G, "Shaun")+COUNTIF(Apr_15!$G:$G, "Shaun")+COUNTIF(Mar_15!$G:$G, "Shaun")
```

The issue I have is, as a month passes, a new sheet for the month is created. So this lowers the automation dramatically as you have to edit the formula every month. I'm basically looking for something that will search G:G across all sheets for that criteria.

So in my imaginary world, it would look something like this:

```
=COUNTIF(ALLSHEETS!$G:$G, "Shaun")
```

**2) Cell Reference as Criterion**

I'm trying to make the criteria look for something from another cell. For example, I'd replace "Shaun" with the cell `L3`. But it doesn't work! It searches for literally the two characters `L` and `3`!

Is there anyway to make the criteria a value from another cell?

Many Thanks,

Shaun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Akshin Jalilov noticed, you will need a script to achieve that. I happen to have written a custom function for that scenario some time ago.

```
/**
 * Counts the cells within the range on multiple sheets.
 *
 * @param {"A1:B23"} range The range to monitor (A1Notation).
 * @param {"valueToCount"} countItem Either a string or a cell reference
 * @param {"Sheet1, Sheet2"} excluded [Optional] - String that holds the names of the sheets that are excluded (comma-separated list);
 * @return {number} The number of times the item appears in the range(s).
 * @customfunction
 */

function COUNTALLSHEETS(range, countItem, excluded) {
    try {
        var count = 0,
            ex = (excluded) ? Trim(excluded.split()) : false;
        SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
            .getSheets()
            .forEach(function (s) {
                if (ex && ex.indexOf(s.getName()) === -1 || !ex) {
                    s.getRange(range)
                        .getValues()
                        .reduce(function (a, b) {
                            return a.concat(b);
                        })
                        .forEach(function (v) {
                            if (v === countItem) count += 1;
                        });
                };
            });
        return count;
    } catch (e) {
        throw e.message;
    }
}

function Trim(v) {
    return v.toString().replace(/^\s\s*/, "")
    .replace(/\s\s*$/, "");
}
```

You can use the custom function in your spreadsheet like this:

```
=COUNTALLSHEETS("B2:B10", "Shaun")
```

or when 'Shaun' is in C2

```
=COUNTALLSHEETS("B2:B3", C2)
```

There is an optional parameter allowing you to provide a string with comma-separated sheet names you wish to exclude from the count. Don't use this paramater if you want to count ALL sheets.

See if that works for you ?

Comment: Love this!!!! Just spent 20 minutes looking for an alternative to entering lots of COUNTIFs. Thank you.

Comment: You also specify an option for when 'Shaun' is in C2
=COUNTALLSHEETS("B2:B3", C2)

How does the script know to search for Shaun using the above function?

Comment: @Frasier013 Because if no quotes are used, the value of C2 is passed to the custom function.

Answer (score 0):

1) Range Across All Sheets:

The only way you can do that is via script, otherwise Spreadsheet functions cannot dynamically read sheets in the spreadsheet.

2) Cell Reference as Criterion

If the value of **L3** is "Shaun" you can do this:

```
=COUNTIF(Aug_15!$G:$G, L3)
```

Make sure that you **don't** put **L3** in quotes.