# Count the number of occurrences of a value on a multi-page spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

The spreadsheet has many pages and more pages will be added in the future and I don't know the names of these future added. I can't just do:

```
=countif(Tab1!A:Z,Value1)+countif(Tab2!A:Z,Value1)+countif(Tab3!A:Z,Value1)...
```

because I don't know the names of these tabs to be added.

Is there a way to count the occurrences on new sheets without explicitly adding them in such a formula?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this can not be achieved using a formula. It must be written as a script. You can see an example at this question: [COUNTIF Statements: Range Across All Sheets + Cell Reference as Criterion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844254/countif-statements-range-across-all-sheets-cell-reference-as-criterion)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if what you're trying to do is possible. But, I can help you with the getting the spreadsheet pages/sheets name part.
By using this [sheets projection](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/migration#projection):

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/{spreadsheetId}/public/basic
```

you'll be able to get the list of all spreadsheet pages in xml format.